# jQuery readonly attribute problems

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
<input type="text" id="tbox" name="tbox" readonly="readonly" />
```

I have a button on which I do this

```
$('#tbox').removeAttr('readonly');
```

I've also tried doing this

```
$('#tbox').attr('readonly', false);
```

.. but none work..

Comment: Your code seems to be alright. Some other code will be generating the error. Try to debug using firebug.

Comment: Use Prop() instead of attr(). See this article, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr. Also, if you are in IE, check the compatibility mode (Tools > "Compatibility View") make sure Compatibility View is not checked.

Answer (score 14):

You will need to do this when the DOM has loaded using jQuery's ready event for the document object. Here's a [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oxiki/1)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tbox').removeAttr('readonly');

});
```

or the shorthand

```
$(function() {

    $('#tbox').removeAttr('readonly');

});
```

**EDIT:**

I just read on [one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919725/trigger-body-click-with-jquery/920265#920265) how `$()` was not working but when you used `jQuery()`, your code worked. That indicates that there is a conflict with the `$` function, most likely due to another JavaScript framework being used on the page too that also uses the `$` shorthand. You can

1- use jQuery's noConflict() to get around this. You can assign the jQuery selector function to a different alias.

2- use`jQuery()` in your code in place of `$()`

3- wrap your jQuery code in a self-invoking anonymous function that will still allow you to use the `$()` shorthand for the jQuery selector inside of it

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {

        $('#tbox').removeAttr('readonly');

    });

})(jQuery);
```

This is an anonymous function that takes one parameter, `$` and is executed immediately, passing in `jQuery` as the argument for that parameter.

Comment: @mathius1 Looks like the example was a victim of a vulnerability in JSBin. I've updated it to point to the correct original example. Thanks for the spot

Answer (score 2):

read article on [jetlogs](http://jetlogs.org/2007/12/16/jquery-disabled-and-readonly-inputs/)

The difference here is that they do

```
<input type="text" id="tbox" name="tbox" readonly />
```

And then

```
$('#tbox').removeAttr('readonly');
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is now Dec 2010, but I just read this post when searching on using JQuery to set and remove READONLY on a form's text box.  I found and use this:

`$('#id-name').attr('readonly', true);  // makes it readonly

$('#id-name').attr('readonly', false); // makes it editable`

Comment: Thanks.. that worked for me. I don't know why but simply using attr("readonly") wouldn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="submit"  id="btn1" onclick="setTimeout(disablefunction, 1);">

    add function of java script
        <script type="text/javascript" >


        function disablefunction() 
        {
            $('#btn1').attr('disabled',true)
        }


        </script>
```

I am sure this will work 100%